# I've Edited my Flash But It Still Using Old Setting?

Tags: flash, adobe, browser-cache

I edited an interactive flash map to link to urls when the counties of the uk are clicked on.

Now I used google.com on Scotland - Abderdeenshire as a test.

I then changed it to link to its proper url and linked another 4/5 but none of them work apart from the initial aberdeenshire linked to google.com

I don't understand as I have now deleted and replaced all files, cleared browser cached and even flash cache.

Why can't I see the updates on my flash map?

it's located on my site Manual Handling Training Hq dot co dot uk

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you show some of the code you're using to accomplish such task?
On the other hand, double check that you're uploading the SWF to the right place. It has happened to me, spent 30 minutes looking at the screen why it wasn't working, until I realized that I was uploading my new file to the wrong directory.